Why we consider color charge as "charge", when they have nothing in common?
In standard model, we all knew about color charges which is mediated by gluons. But why we call it as "charge" when it has nothing common with conventional electric charge? It could be considerable if the difference was limited to the forces and polarities ,but their are significant difference between the characteristics of interactions of these two charge types. Some major differences are described below:

Charge exchange: In electromagnetic interaction, photon do not exchanges charge. after the interaction, the source charges remain same. Gluons on the other hand do indeed exchanges color charge.
Charge of the force carriers: Beside exchanging color charge, some gluons (excluding 3 component gluons) have their own color charges. Meanwhile, photon is charge less even though it interacts with charged particles.
Amounts of force carriers needed: It needs a lot of photons to cause electromagnetic interaction. But it needs only a few gluons to cause strong interaction (thus it called non-radiating interaction). And the reason is obvious too. The photons has much lower frequency than gluons, and that's why few gluons have energy equivalent to a lot of soft photons. Here I said soft photons because general purpose electromagnetic attraction/repulsion requires photons  with frequencies below radio frequency. But what about photons with higher frequency? At higher frequency, fewer photons could interacts with charges (i.e. molecular rotation, plasma oscillation, photoelectric effect, compton scattering, electron ejection etc). But we couldn't compare these interaction with electromagnetic attraction/repulsion, because they do identical action on both positive and negative charge.

So, What do you think? Is color charge really considerable as a conventional charge?

Are you familiar with Noether's theorem?

This question is similar to: Mathematically, what is color charge? and the links therein. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The first and second difference you mention are actually the same (gluons carry color charge). The third one you mention is simply wrong (the amount of photons and gluons involved in a process can vary, that's the same in both cases). So there is just one difference, why would that make it invalid to point out the many similarities?

This is a semantics question, not a physics one.

@Jeanbaptiste And apart from the semantics, it's a judgement problem: when are things similar enough to say that they are in the same category? In this case we would need to know the precise definition of the concept "charge" to answer that question. I think most physicists would define it as "some property of a field that determines its interactions". And in that case color charge would fit in perfectly.

See also weak charge. One approach to this question would be a comparison of the different charges in each sector of the $\rm SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ standard model. The $\rm U(1)$ electric charge, which is the massless projection of the $\rm SU(2)\times U(1)$ unified electroweak interaction, doesn't have enough degrees of freedom to display all the complexity of the $\rm SU(3)$ color charge.

Alos, like, SU(3) QCD , while a very difficult practical thing to solve for, solution wise, is a pretty clear generalization from U(1) QED, and you have to call the generalized charges something
